# If $a(u,u) \leq \liminf a(u_n, u_n)$, is $a(u,u) \leq \liminf a(u_n, u_{n-1})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence, semicontinuous-functions

Let $a\colon H \times H \to \mathbb{R}$ be some bilinear form and $H$ is a Hilbert space. If it is weak lsc, i.e.,
$$a(u,u) \leq \liminf a(u_n, u_n)$$
for a sequence $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $H$, then is $$a(u,u) \leq \liminf a(u_n, u_{n-1})$$
true? Or is there some name for this kind of property?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. Take $a$ to be the inner product and consider the sequence
$$
e_1, -e_1, e_2, -e_2, \ldots,
$$
where $(e_i)$ is an infinite orthonormal system.

I do not think that many bilinear forms $a$ have this property (unless there is some compactness hidden in $a$).